# My war in eclipse doesn't see jars from other projects

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have a gradle multiple projects like this:

```
root
----service-jar
----war-project
```

When I include these projects in my eclipse, the war project hasn't jars of service-jar in the classpath, so I can't deploy my war in a server.

If I deploy the generated war from war-project/build/libs to my jboss server, all work fine.

Maybe I have a bad configuration for eclipse plugin.

Here is my settings.gradle:

```
include 'service-jar', 'war-project'
```

Here is my root/build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            name "jboss"
            url "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/"
        }
}
```

Here is my service-jar/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.7.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.7.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.7.RELEASE',
}
```

Finally, here is my war-project/build.gradle:

```
dependsOn(':service-jar')
apply plugin: 'war'
dependencies {
    compile project(':service-jar')
    providedCompile
        'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5',
        'javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1',
        'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2',
        'com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.1.6',
        'com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.1.6',

}
```

What is wrong in my configuration ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Here is my .classpath from the war project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="/service-jar" exported="true"/>

        <classpathentry sourcepath="/Users/Kiva/.gradle/caches/artifacts-8/filestore/org.springframework/spring-bean/3.0.7.RELEASE/source/d7c3dd79ae7c222bdd4b310181a5220b13915e3d/spring-bean-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="/Users/Kiva/.gradle/caches/artifacts-8/filestore/org.springframework/spring-bean/3.0.7.RELEASE/jar/29ef19d319b28e02bcb4893bd4badba80003a88b/spring-bean-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar" exported="true">
        <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="../"/>
    </attributes>
       <!-- The same for all extern dependencies -->
</classpath>
```

Comment: Good question. Looks fine to me. I can comment though that the compile dependency implies a general dependency, so the dependsOn(':service-jar') is redundant.

Comment: How does your .classpath file look like? This is the file that is generated when you run 'gradle eclipse'. Also. Do you run the eclipse task from the root of the project?

Comment: Yes I run the eclipse task from the root. I run gradle eclipse eclipseWtp

Comment: @Kiva: And what is in your .classpath file?

Comment: I have updated my post with the .classpath file

Comment: The ```.classpath``` file looks find, though using ```dependsOn(':service-jar')``` in ```war-project/build.gradle``` you will get an error running Gradle because just ```Task```s provide the ```dependsOn``` feature